# Is it possible to encrypt a hard drive that is dual booting ubuntu using rEFInd?

Tags: hard-drive, partition, filevault, encryption, efi

I recently installed ubuntu on my macbook pro. I am using rEFInd to dual boot ubuntu. Following the installation, I tried to encrypt my `Macintosh HD` partition by first converting the disk to core storage. I received the following error message:

`Error: -69730: Unable to create boot loader partition due to the specifics of your partition map layout`

I was using FileVault for whole disk encryption before partitioning my hard drive in order to install Ubuntu. Is there any way to correct this error, or another method to encrypt my hard drive?

I am dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 on my 13 inch Macbook Pro from mid 2014 running El Capitan. This is what my partition lay-out looks like:

[image]

Comment: It would help if you would include the year/screen size of your Mac. Basically, what is shown on the pop up window when you select "About this Mac" from the menu bar. Also include the exact name of the Ubuntu file you downloaded. The image you posted does not contain any Linux partitions. To what partition did you install rEFInd? What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: I just edited the question to include some of these details. My computer is a mid 2014 13 inch Macbook Pro running El Capitan. I installed rEFInd to Ubuntu on disk0s4. I copied the Ubuntu disk image (ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso) to a flash drive to install it. I used this as a guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pdW4DAvJDM.

Answer (score -2):

If you encrypt the OS X partition only.

Comment: I was trying to encrypt only the OS X partition when the error message appeared. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: what is the code or error message?

Comment: I tried to convert my OS X partition to core storage in order to encrypt it and received this message: `Error: -69730: Unable to create boot loader partition due to the specifics of your partition map layout.` I've added a photo of my partition layout to the original question if it helps.

Comment: Are you booting windows or Linux with rEFInd?

Comment: I'm booting Linux.

Comment: A bit of googling found something relating to rEFInd and full disk encryption: 
https://iocrunch.com/2014/02/linux-dual-boot-on-mac-with-full-disk-encryption/

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the page. Unfortunately that method uses FileVault for whole disk encryption. When I tried to encrypt using FileVault, I received the error message: FileVault can't be turned on for the disk "Macintosh HD." Some disk formats don’t support the recovery partition required by encryption. To use encryption, reinstall this version of OS X on a reformatted disk.

Comment: I installed Linux via CD, if you remove rEFInd and its corresponding partitions, and install Linux via a CD , and then try again encrypting your disk. I never liked rEFInd, when their is a far simpler method.